# Buckyballs in vacuum

Tags: chemical-compounds, condensed-matter

I've read about the idea that buckyballs and other nanostructures could be used to hold drugs and things until they reach certain places in the body and then get released.

So I was wondering, if you created a buckyball in air, so that some molecules that are in air (such as oxygen and nitrogen) were inside the buckyball. if you then put the buckyball in a vacuum, would the air be able to escape, or would it be trapped in the buckyball.

(And vice versa, a buckyball created in a vacuum put into the atmosphere, would any molecules fit through into the buckyball?)

Comment: related link: http://www.nasa.gov/home/hqnews/2010/jul/HQ_10-174_Buckyballs.html

Comment: As a side comment: that the buckyballs are used to "hold drugs and things" is a slightly incomplete description. AFAIK often-times what is used is not a whole buckball but part of a fullerene with a portion removed/open, and a separate "stopper" molecule to close the hole. See e.g. doi:10.1002/anie.201004879

Comment: I'm not sure that's just what my chemistry teacher said could happen, she's a doctor and used to work with medicines and things so she probably knows what she's talking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just that the buckyball's faces are not holes as in popular view; there is pretty much electron probability density there forming quite a strong barrier. Also the size of the faces is comparable to the size of a, for instance, oxygen molecule, so I'm pretty sure that it is impossible for a buckyball to release a molecule just because of one atmosphere pressure difference; yet I don't really think that anything can be put inside without a targeted, careful procedure.

EDIT: A picture of C60, with, I hope, van der Waals surface. This shows that this structure is indeed pretty dense.
[image]

Comment: how did you generate this image? I'd be interested in finding tools like this